# mysql on duplicate key generate number

Tags: mysql

I have the following query that i use to insert some data from a csv file that contains duplicates on codes.

```
INSERT INTO table_name (ProductCode) VALUES (23) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ProductCode = FLOOR(RAND() * 500)
```

The problem with the above query is that it always fails

```
Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '88' for key 'ProductCode' in
```

How can i do my query so if the key already exists generate another one and continue with the inserts?

Comment: so that means the insert was a dupe, and the update via random was a dupe too?

Comment: yes. for example i have Product code 4875 7 times. The product code is the same but the rest of the data is different. That means i have to insert everything.

Comment: Looks like the update is failing and not the insert.  See error message properly

Comment: you (one would hope) have a unique index on `ProductCode`. So my comment up there is the update via random failing

Comment: yes i have a unique key on ProductCode :-D

Comment: so an IODKU has the update half being the safety net of the whole thing. Meaning, you want data to change. Either an insert, or an update to a pre-existing (B) let's call it. But when it comes time to update B, you say B really should be C but C already exists. So you cut a big whole in your safety net

Comment: Why would you replace an existing product code with a randomly generated one in case the product code in the csv file is a duplicate? Insert ... on duplicate key update ... is useful if you want to merge the new record with the existing one in case their PK matches. If you want to generate a new product code and insert the record from the csv file, then use either plain insert with error handling or import data into a staging table and use insert selects to do the importing of the data into its final destination table.

Comment: or any unique key not just a PK. So get this data into a staging table as Shadow says. Perhaps even stage it again with a `DISTINCT` . But right now this whole thing is so dubious it is an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: did i just get -1 because i asked a question where i didn't know the answer nor how to proper use the functions from mysql ? seems that SO serves -1 just for fun :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple way to do this query would be to do a while in php and from there check if the product code is unique or not and if it's not unique generate a new one. don't forget to -1 the answer cuz i won't post the code how i did it just to make sure i get -1 :-). I heard it takes less time to do -1 on a question and move on when no one know's a good way to do it.